# JBPM project never finishes building

Tags: jbpm

I have a JBPM application with a dependency on WorkItemHandlers (WIH's).  Until yesterday it built in seconds.  Now it takes 20 minutes to build.  The changes I made in my WIH's and workflow since yesterday seem trivial - the most likely culprit being my adding a dependency to kie-server-client to the WIH. The project has no rules - except possibly as gateway conditions -  but log errors imply Business Central thinks the project has rules.

What do you think is the remedy given the following from the logs?

```
15:03:38,138 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieProject] (default task-9) No files found for KieBase KiePMML-Cluster-Rules
15:12:07,897 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieProject] (default task-9) No files found for KieBase KiePMML-Tree-Rules
15:16:06,359 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieProject] (default task-9) No files found for KieBase KiePMML-Bayes-Rules
15:20:00,406 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieProject] (default task-9) No files found for KieBase KiePMML-Neural-Rules
15:20:00,407 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieProject] (default task-9) No files found for KieBase KiePMML-Regression-Rules
15:20:00,408 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieProject] (default task-9) No files found for KieBase KiePMML-SVM-Rules
No files found for KieBase KiePMML-Scorecard-Rules
```

And this is the new dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kie.server</groupId>
      <artifactId>kie-server-client</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org-kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-dmn-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org-optaplanner</groupId>
                <artifactId>optaplanner-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>       
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org-optaplanner</groupId>
                <artifactId>optaplanner-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org-drools</groupId>
                <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
      <!--version>${version.org.kie}</version-->
    </dependency>
```

If I stop the build I see these interesting pieces of the log:

```
2021-10-27 09:15:24,684 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieProject] (default task-4) No files found for KieBase KiePMML-Cluster-Rules  <---- I STOP THE SERVER ON THIS.  IN MINUTES IT PRODUCES 2 SIMILAR LINES
2021-10-27 09:18:05,603 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0272: Suspending server
2021-10-27 09:18:05,696 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (Thread-2) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
2021-10-27 09:18:05,699 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
2021-10-27 09:18:05,723 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = business-central.war
2021-10-27 09:18:05,730 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = business-central.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_8_0
2021-10-27 09:18:05,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = business-central.war_org.postgresql.Driver_42_2
2021-10-27 09:18:05,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = business-central.war_org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver_1_3
...

2021-10-27 09:18:06,398 ERROR [org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.core.Builder] (default task-4) Rules compilation failed or interrupted: java.lang.RuntimeException: Rules compilation failed or interrupted
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.compileRulesLevel(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1146)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.compileRules(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1107)
...
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalInterruptibleAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:367)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1001)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.compileRulesLevel(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1144)
    ... 102 more

2021-10-27 09:18:06,459 WARN  [Sisu] (default task-4) Error injecting: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
...

2021-10-27 09:18:06,473 ERROR [org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder] (default task-4) Unable to build MavenEmbedder: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.LegacyRepositorySystem
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem

1 error
      role: org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem
  roleHint: 
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
 ...

2021-10-27 09:18:06,499 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4) org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-000229: Contextual reference of Managed Bean [class org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalBuildExecConfigExecutor] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] is not valid after container business-central.war shutdown
2021-10-27 09:18:06,500 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)     at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:85)
2021-10-27 09:18:06,500 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)     at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:131)
2021-10-27 09:18:06,500 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)     at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalBuildExecConfigExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.outputId(Unknown Source)
2021-10-27 09:18:06,500 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)     at org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.lambda$continuePipeline$0(PipelineExecutor.java:111)
2021-10-27 09:18:06,500 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)     at org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.StageUtil$1.execute(StageUtil.java:38)

...

2021-10-27 09:18:07,110 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment kie-server.war (runtime-name: kie-server.war) in 1387ms
2021-10-27 09:18:08,657 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment business-central.war (runtime-name: business-central.war) in 2936ms
...
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_261-b12
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
...
    java.version = 1.8.0_261
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.261-b12
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    jboss.home.dir = C:\Users\dgoldstein\Downloads\rhpam7-install-demo-master\target\jboss-eap-7.3
...
    user.variant = 
2021-10-27 09:18:23,397 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-2) VM Arguments: -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms3G -Xmx6144m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2048m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -verbose:gc -Xloggc:C:\Users\dgoldstein\Downloads\rhpam7-install-demo-master\target\jboss-eap-7.3\standalone\log\gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\Users\dgoldstein\Downloads\rhpam7-install-demo-master\target\jboss-eap-7.3\standalone\log\server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:C:\Users\dgoldstein\Downloads\rhpam7-install-demo-master\target\jboss-eap-7.3\standalone\configuration/logging.properties
```

Comment: When I use an earlier version of the WIH jar, it builds.  I think I need to exclude something from the  kie-server-client import - but what?

Comment: I retried the current version of the WIH's and the build finishes - but takes about 30x as long.  And the code difference is not significant.

Answer (score 0):

In Business Central I had allowed my WorkItemHandler jar to be visible so that a class it defined could be used.  This apparently triggered a bug in PAM/JBPM where it would search for files of rules on the disk - despite there being no rules in the application.  I removed references to the new class and turned off visibility into the dependent JAR and the problem disappeared.